# My keyboard is short circuited due to water

Tags: keyboard

earlier today, I accidentally flipped    the water bottle onto 7my laptop's keyboard. It was fine, until I put it in a bag and  went home from office.

The laptop buttons are now short circuited, or at least that's what I think happened. For example, the "7" button won't work and the "m" button prints "7m" together, and    other such issues.

What should  I do? Wait for it or should I unscrew my laptop and put it under the sun or what?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but this is a "cruel yet fair" enough answer on how to consider "water in computers" - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275

Comment: The best thing you can do is take it the laptop apart, let it air out really good. You could then try the original keyboard you have to see if it works fine, or you could try a new keyboard to see what happens with a new one. If a new keyboard still causes issues, then it's probably something on the motherboard that is short circuited.

Comment: The main cause of **permanent** damage after a water spill is electrolytic (galvanic) corrosion, caused by electricity from the batteries and power supply going through the electrolyte (water with impurities). The first thing to do is to remove power supply and the main battery, and, if accessible, the clock battery (which may cause loss of BIOS settings, though). Dry it out, and only after it's thoroughly dry replace batteries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shut down your laptop **RIGHT NOW** and remove the battery if possible!!!

Whatever you do, do not put the keyboard near an electric heater, or open flame. Do not use a hair dryer. Putting it in direct sunlight for prolonged periods is less likely to cause problems, but still not recommended.

I would recommend getting your laptop serviced until the water inside shorts anything else like the mainboard.

If only a small portion of water got in, and your laptop looks water-resistant enough, leaving it alone for about a day might help, but this is still risky.

If you simply do not have funds, you could try to disassemble it. Find a disassembly guide for your laptop online and be extra careful.

If you are able to remove the keyboard, put it on the side and shake it gently to get some of the water out. After that let it dry for a day or so. Drying it in a vertical position may help a bit.

If above did not help, especially if you drowned the keyboard in a sweet or salty water, salt may have formed a short. You may need to put the keyboard into a tub of distilled water for a few hours. (Some pharmacies may sell distilled water. Tap water is not enough, and bottled mineral water will cause even more problems.) Let it dry for another day after that. If it still didn't help, you may try pouring spirit into the keyboard (extra clean spirits only, do not use alcohol drinks!), putting it into a plastic bag for a few hours, and then letting it dry for a few more hours. This may kill or discolor your keyboard though, and is still not guaranteed to help.

It is extremely tedious to remove and reinstall keycaps from laptops, and it is most likely impossible to access lower level, so there is most likely no point in trying to disassemble a keyboard itself.

If nothing helps, or you chose not to experiment, you may need a new keyboard. Some laptop models make it relatively easy to replace a keyboard, which may cost as low as $10 - just be very careful and follow replacement instruction for your laptop model.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, unlucky.
You are generally ok with water if you let it dry out before switching it back on.

But, it does sound as if you have a short somewhere on the system. The water has potentially dislodged some debris that has shorted something on your system,

So, can you fix it?
Possibly, it depends on what the actual problem is. If it's as I described above then you may be able to clean it with some surgical spirits and a lint free brush cloth

If you can get access to your laptop keyboard, do that and first of all just make sure its perfectly dry. Then you can have a brush with a fine paintbrush.
You can also try to clean the board with spirits. basically, this will clean the board and evaporate, so no residue to worry about.

It's highly flammable, so take care and ensure your machine is switched off first.